# SQL Union with Conditional Field

Tags: sql-server, union

I have the following (simplified) tables:

```
No0    |    No1    |    start0    |    end0
10000  |           |              |
19999  |           |     10000    |    19999
20000  |           |              |
29999  |           |     20000    |    29999


No0    |    No1    |    start0    |    end0
       |   11000   |              |     
       |   15950   |              |    15950
       |   16000   |              |
```

How can I `UNION` them (or other method), but fill in the appropriate `No0` on the 2nd table based on `No1` being between `start0` and `end0` so that it returns:

```
No0    |    No1    |    start0    |    end0
10000  |           |              |
19999  |           |     10000    |    19999
20000  |           |              |
29999  |           |     20000    |    29999
19999  |   11000   |              |     
19999  |   15950   |              |    
19999  |   16000   |              |
```

Comment: Why woudn't a simple union statement work?  `Select * from table1 UNION ALL Select * from table2`

Comment: You're basically asking for a JOIN on the select in table 2, it has nothing to do with UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the lower half of the union, join back to TableA where No1 is between Start0 and End0.

**Here is an example:**

```
select      ta.No0,
            ta.No1,
            ta.Start0,
            ta.End0
from        TableA  as  ta
union all
select      ta.No0,
            tb.No1,
            NULL as Start0,
            NULL as End0
from        TableB  as  tb
inner join  TableA  as  ta  on  tb.No1 between ta.Start0 and ta.End0;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1b759/1)

Comment: Got to be quick on the trigger and you have a faster draw. +1

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be pretty simple but you wouldn't believe how much time I spent spinning my wheels.